# django trouble iterating dict in template

Tags: python, django, templates, dictionary

I have the following data in the template

```
{u'D - content a': [<Person: first_name last_name>, <Person: first_name last_name>, <Person: first_name last_name>],
 u'D - contant b': [<Person: first_name last_name>],
 u'D - content c': [<Person: first_name last_name>]
 }
```

And I'd like to have it like this:

```
h2 -> Content a
    list with three people

h2 -> content b
    list with one person

h3 -> content c
    list with one person
```

But I can't find out how two write it. My attempt:

```
    {% for key, value in persons %}
        <h2>{{ key }}</h2>
        {{ value }}
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`dict.items`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) (or [`dict.iteritems`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) if you use Python 2.x):

```
{% for item in persons.items %}
    <h2>{{ item.0 }}</h2>
    {{ item.1 }}
{% endfor %}
```